# анимированное Меню бургер

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не получается создать значок в форме X, как можно исправить?

```
.navbar__hamburger {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    transition: all 10s ease-in 0;
}

.hamburger__line {
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 16px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.navbar__hamburger:hover .hamburger__line:first-child {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.navbar__hamburger:hover .hamburger__line:nth-child(2) {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: transparent;
}

.navbar__hamburger:hover .hamburger__line:last-child {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Типа этого?

```css
.navbar__hamburger {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    transition: all 10s ease-in 0;
}

.hamburger__line {
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 32px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.navbar__hamburger:hover .hamburger__line:first-child {
    transform: translate3d(0, 4px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.navbar__hamburger:hover .hamburger__line:nth-child(2) {
    background: transparent;
}

.navbar__hamburger:hover .hamburger__line:last-child {
   transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar__hamburger">
  <span class="hamburger__line"></span>
  <span class="hamburger__line"></span>
  <span class="hamburger__line"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: translate3d(0px, -4px, 0); а откуда 4px?

Comment: @George что значит откуда? translate3d считает по трём направлениям (x,y,z), то есть горизонталь вертикаль и угол вроде как. Ну так вот я сдвинул на 4px по вертикали, чтобы ровно встали палочки и образовали крестик.

Comment: Все уже понял, спасибо

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, честно говоря, из ваших слов ничего не понятно. У меня лично тоже вышло 4px, но у меня так получилось в результате сложения `gap` и `height`. Можете объяснить снова? В противоположном случае, не особо вижу логики в ваших действиях.

Comment: @ΝNL993 что значит не видите логики? Тут не нужна логика, просто сдвигаешь по вертикали и если нужно по горизонтали до тех пор, пока не получится красивый симметричный крестик. Панель разработчика есть в браузере для подгонки размеров.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, то есть вы хотите сказать, что вы сами не знаете как правильное получить значение, не перебирая их всех подряд? Мягко говоря, это плохо.

Comment: @ΝNL993 почему не зная? Я вижу, что палочка стоит ниже чем она должна быть и по вертикали поднимаю её до тех пор, пока меня не устроит. Верстка - это визуал, а не программирование. Вы же тоже ставите например отступ 15px и проверяете реально ли там 15px отступ, ведь там может быть у другого элемента тоже отступ, но внутренний и вы будете думать, что 15px, а на самом деле 20px. И я не перебирал их все подряд, я только по высоте поднял и я знал, что поднимать)).